# How should I calculate the surface area of a 3D Mesh file

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, three.js, mesh

How should I calculate the surface area of a 3D Mesh file. 
Is there any predefined function for surface area calculation. I am working on a project, where after selecting picture volume and area gets calculated automatically in there field.

Comment: The sum of areas of all the triangles in a mesh?

Comment: no , the figure is not triangular shape.

Comment: Do you use quads? What revision of Three.js?

Comment: Please, read about [ask] and [mcve]. So far, it's very unclear what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 def crossVectors(a,b):
    P = {}
    ax = b[0]['X']
    ay = b[0]['Y']
    az = b[0]['Z']
    bx = b[1]['X']
    by = b[1]['Y']
    bz = b[1]['Z']
    P['X'] = ay * bz - az * by
    P['Y'] = az * bx - ax * bz
    P['Z'] = ax * by - ay * bx
    return P

 def find_mins_maxs(self, obj):
    minx = maxx = miny = maxy = minz = maxz = None
    # print"##############", obj #dir(obj)

    arr1 = obj.points
    length_1 =len(arr1)
    _area = 0.0;
    va ={}
    vb = {}
    vc = {} 
    ab= {}
    ac= {}
    val = []
    if length_1 ==0:
        return 0.0
    i= 0;
    while i<length_1-2:
        va['X'] = arr1[i][0]
        va['Y'] = arr1[i][1]
        va['Z'] = arr1[i][2]
        vb['X'] = arr1[i+1][0]
        vb['Y'] = arr1[i+1][1]
        vb['Z'] = arr1[i+1][2]
        vc['X'] = arr1[i+2][0]
        vc['Y'] = arr1[i+2][1]
        vc['Z'] = arr1[i+2][2]
        ab['X'] = vb['X']-va['X']
        ab['Y'] = vb['Y']-va['Y']
        ab['Z'] = vb['Z']-va['Z']
        ac['X'] = vc['X']-va['X']
        ac['Y'] = vc['Y']-va['Y']
        ac['Z'] = vc['Z']-va['Z']
        val.append(ab)
        val.append(ac)
        cross= self.crossVectors(val)
        _area +=np.sqrt(np.power(cross['X'],2)+np.power(cross['Y'],2)+np.power(cross['Z'],2))/2;
        i+=9;
        area = np.abs(_area)/100
        fractiondigits =2
        area =round(area*np.power(10,fractiondigits))/np.power(10,fractiondigits)
        print"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@",area
    return area
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct method to get the area but you can create your own custom logic. The logic is to create triangles out of your mesh and calculate there area and add them which will be equals to the area of your mesh.

The example is as follows:

```
function crossVectors( a, b ) {
   var ax = a.X, ay = a.Y, az = a.Z;
   var bx = b.X, by = b.Y, bz = b.Z;
    var P={X:ay * bz - az * by,
          Y:az * bx - ax * bz,
          Z:ax * by - ay * bx}

   return P;
}
 function SuperficialAreaOfMesh(points) {

   var _len =points.length,
      _area = 0.0;

   if (!_len) return 0.0;

   var i= 0,vols=0;
   var va,vb,vc;
   do  {
      va={X:points[i],Y:points[i+1],Z:points[i+2]};
      vb={X:points[i+3],Y:points[i+4],Z:points[i+5]};
      vc={X:points[i+6],Y:points[i+7],Z:points[i+8]};

      var ab = {X:vb.X-va.X,Y:vb.Y-va.Y,Z:vb.Z-va.Z};
         //vb.clone().sub(va);  var ac = {X:vc.X-va.X,Y:vc.Y-va.Y,Z:va.Z-vc.Z};
      //vc.clone().sub(va);   var cross = new THREE.Vector3();
      cross=crossVectors( ab, ac );
      _area += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cross.X,2)+Math.pow(cross.Y,2)+Math.pow(cross.Z,2))/2;
      i+=9;
   }
   while (i<points.length);

   return customRound(Math.abs(_area)/100,2);

}
// Let's say you have mesh named mesh
SuperficialAreaOfMesh(mesh.vertices);
```

The example above follows the tutorial found [here](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-uepuawvq-tr.html).

[Here is another nice logic for your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518139/threejs-3d-object-area-calculation-triangulated).

Comment: For less code, it could be done with `THREE.Triangle()` and its [`.getArea()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Triangle.getArea) method.

Comment: Dimensions X,Y,Z value is given but i dont know what formula i have to use for calculating surface area of a3D file.

Comment: Try using the above logic. It will return you the area.

Comment: Actually I am getting area as an array and function takes only 2 arguments.
Please Help me.....
[0.10762328 0.02869747 0.11791313 0.11009426 0.04056691 0.11645208
 0.10868461 0.03259173 0.12078221]

Comment: @UllasHunka
Actually my points comes up as nested array [[12.671184    4.1647673  13.446729   ... 12.671184    4.1647673
  13.946729  ]
 [12.303494    2.7925358  13.946729   ... 12.671184    4.1647673
  13.946729  ]
 [12.303494    2.7925358  13.446729   ... 12.303494    2.7925358
  13.946729  ]
 ...
 [ 1.0177865   6.900198   14.36       ...  0.84364206  6.250282
  14.36      ]
 [ 1.3021419   7.51       19.36       ...  1.0177865   6.900198
  14.36      ]
 [ 1.3021419   7.51       14.36       ...  1.0177865   6.900198
  14.36      ]]

Comment: My Code
def find_mins_maxs(self, obj):
        arr1 = obj.points
        length_1 =len(arr1)
        _area = 0.0;
        va = vb = vc = {}
        if length_1 ==0:
            return 0.0
        i= 0;
        while i<=length_1-2:
            va['X'] = arr1[i]
            va['Y'] = arr1[i+1]
            va['Z'] = arr1[i+2]
            _area += np.sqrt(np.power(va['X'],2)+np.power(va['Y'],2)+np.power(va['Z'],2))/2;
            i+=3;
            area = np.abs(_area)/100
            y = self.custom(area,2)
        return y

Comment: Can you please update your question with the points so that I can see and can update the logic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176206/discussion-between-ullas-hunka-and-priya).